# Hook up application insights manually

Tags: macos, azure, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-mac

I'm using VS for macOS community to develop a asp.net core site and unfortunately theres no "Add Application insights telemetry".

That makes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core kinda not very helpful...

so, how can i hook it up manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the changes manually. There are 3 things to be done.

1. Edit your .csproj to bring ApplicationInsights by adding this line.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.1" />`

2. Modify Program.cs to include a call to UseApplicationInsights() as shown below.

   `public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseApplicationInsights()
           .Build();`
3. Add you instrumentation key - either as a parameter to UseApplicationInsights() above or in appsettings.json

   `{
     "ApplicationInsights": {
       "InstrumentationKey": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"
     }
   }`

Now run the application, and telemetry will start flowing to Application Insights,

These steps are described in the wiki as well:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/StartingDoc

Comment: thats it? when I added app insights on regular projects in the past, i remember that a bunch of other files were created and that there were a bunch of steps on the VS process.... like 4-5 levels of installation or something

Comment: the VS process is pretty trivial too: it just adds nuget packages and modifies some config files, and if necessary does some code injection if necesary